# Is it possible to send transaction in Binance Smart Chain using web3 and ethereumjs-tx?

Tags: javascript

I want to send transaction in Binance Smart Chain and I got an error: new Error("Chain with name " + chain + " not supported");

```
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;
const Web3 = require('web3');


const web3 = new Web3("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/xxx");

const privKey =
    Buffer.from('xxx', 'hex');
const addressFrom = '0xXXX';
const addressTo = '0xXXX';


web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addressFrom, (err, txCount) => {
        const txObject = {
            nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
            to: addressTo,
            value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.01', 'ether')),
            gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(100000),
            gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('100', 'gwei'))
        };

        const tx = new Tx(txObject,  {'chain':'smart chain'});
        //const tx = new Tx(txObject,  {'chain':'56'});
        //const tx = new Tx(txObject,  {'chain':'binance'});
        tx.sign(privKey);

        const serializedTrans = tx.serialize();
        const raw = '0x' + serializedTrans.toString('hex');

        web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err, txHash) => {
            console.log('txHash:', txHash)
        });
    }
);
```

And if using these libraries it is impossible to send a transaction, what is better for me to use to send a transaction in Smart Chain?
I found a couple of sites https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/wallet/wallet_api.html and https://github.com/drunken005/binance-utils but it seems to me they are for a regular Binance network (as I see wallets in examples start with bnb...) or am I wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Infura does not support BSC, instead try another provider like shown [here](https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/create-wallet.html)

```
// mainnet 
const web3 = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443');
// testnet
const web3 = new Web3('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545');
```

Or use providers like quikNode

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
import Common from 'ethereumjs-common';
import transaction from 'ethereumjs-tx';

const common = Common.default.forCustomChain('mainnet', {
  name: 'bnb',
  networkId: 56,
  chainId: 56
}, 'petersburg');

const tx = new transaction.Transaction(data, {
  common
});
```

Comment: if you want to use Binance Smart Chain testnet, do you know the configuration? using the same code with id: 97 and name 'Chapel' I get this error: 'Error: Chain with name Chapel not supported'

Comment: for Binance smart chain testnet it worked for me:

Answer (score 0):

For Binance smart chain testnet it worked fine:

```
         const createRawTransaction = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;
         const common = require('ethereumjs-common');

          const chain = common.default.forCustomChain(
            'mainnet',{
              name: 'bnb',
              networkId: 97,
              chainId: 97
            },
            'petersburg'
          )
          var rawTx = new createRawTransaction(rawData, {common: chain});
```