# How to sign a transaction using web3.js and ethereumjs-tx on the BSC testnet

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, bsc, ethereumjs-tx, sendtransaction

How do I sign and send a transaction using web3.js and ethereumjs-tx on the BSC testnet?

I have found this question and answer:

[Is it possible to send transaction in Binance Smart Chain using web3 and ethereumjs-tx?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/92806/is-it-possible-to-send-transaction-in-binance-smart-chain-using-web3-and-ethereu)

This only seems to cover the mainnet:

```
const common = Common.default.forCustomChain('mainnet', {
  name: 'bnb',
  networkId: 56,
  chainId: 56
}, 'petersburg');
```

If I substitute the chainId for 97 (BSC Testnet Id) and replace 'petersburg' with Chapel. I get 'Error: Chain with name Chapel not supported'

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not the answer, but Petersburg is the name of hardfork (update) and not the chain

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't noticed that. I assume the fork would be the same for the BSC Testnet then? I'll try swapping over just the networkId and chainId to 97.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up trying to ethereumjs-tx in the end as I came across this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64526925/how-to-swap-tokens-on-uniswap-using-web3-js

Managed to get that solution up and running it solved that particular error I was getting.

Answer (score 0):

First argument can only have 5 possible values, mainnet, ropsten, rinkeby, goerli and kovan. You can confirm [here](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-common/blob/master/src/chains/index.ts).

But you can work around that by overriding parameters with second argument.
So in your case...

```
var common = Common.forCustomChain(
    'ropsten',
    {
        name: 'Binance Smart Chain Testnet',
        networkId: 97,
        chainId: 97,
        url: 'https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545'
    },
    'istanbul',
);
```

should work. 97 is BSC testnet network and chain id.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked like charm for me:

```
    var common = Common.custom({ chainId: 97 }, { hardfork: 'istanbul' });
```

This works well for binance testnet.