# Web3js (NodeJS)Error: Hardfork with name function (), please help me

Tags: web3js, error

I'm trying to transfer for BSC network (testnet) using web3 with NodeJS. However, I am getting an error that I can't find any source on the internet. Would you help me with this topic?

Thanks for help.

Error line.
[image]

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
const Common = require('ethereumjs-common').default;

const Web3js = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/'))

let tokenAddress = '0xd648d2d7a0b312c6464d1ea10723f670269f09d4'
let toAddress = '0x238BC31CeBd242fA4F8baC5e6Cc1fB272E79d221'
let fromAddress = '0x59eed5ACf8274263Db17190690ff6842Bd7b3593'
let privateKey = Buffer.from('PRIVATE-KEY', 'hex')

let contractABI = ['ABI CODE']

let contract = new Web3js.eth.Contract(contractABI, tokenAddress, { from: fromAddress })

let amount = 10;
var gasPriceGwei = 3;
var gasLimit = 3000000;


const BSC_MAIN = Common.forCustomChain(
    'mainnet', {
    name: 'bnb',
    networkId: 56,
    chainId: 56
},
    'petersburg'
)
Web3js.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress)
    .then((count) => {
        let rawTransaction = {
            'from': fromAddress,
            'gasPrice': Web3js.utils.toHex(gasPriceGwei * 1e9),
            'gasLimit': Web3js.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
            'to': tokenAddress,
            'value': 0x0,
            'data': contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, amount).encodeABI(),
            'nonce': Web3js.utils.toHex(count)
        }

        let transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction, BSC_MAIN)
        transaction.sign(privateKey)
        Web3js.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex'))
            .on('transactionHash', console.log)
    })
```

Comment: Please help me..

Comment: Can you check if something from here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99012/how-to-sign-a-transaction-using-web3-js-and-ethereumjs-tx-on-the-bsc-testnet will help?

Comment: @Ismael Unfortunately the solutions in this thread do not apply to me :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and found that the custom chain needs to be specified as common.  For example this change to your code should get rid of the error:

```
let transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction, {common: BSC_MAIN})
```

see the examples: https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx/blob/master/examples/custom-chain-tx.ts#L21-L29